# Nested wildcards with lower bounds

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

So I read through the main Java Generic FAQ and the single thing which is holding me up are nested wildcards with lower bounds. I want to give you an example of what I do understand, something specifically which works and how I view it. Maybe you could tell me the way I am thinking about this is wrong even though the compiler isn't complaining in the "good" case.

**Example 1 (makes sense):**

```
static void WildcardsMethod(List<? extends Pair<? extends Number>> list)
{
    System.out.println("It worked");
}

static void TestWildcardsMethod()
{
    List<Pair<Integer>> list = null;
    WildcardsMethod(list);
}
```

I first look at the deepest wildcard and bound in WildcardMethod's signature. It is looking for `Pair<? extends Number>`. Therefore, I could use `Pair<Integer>`, `Pair<Double>` and so on. Now I have something which looks like the below code in my mind if I decided to substitute `Pair<Integer>` for `Pair<? extends Number>`:

```
List<? extends Pair<Integer>>
```

Now, the wildcard represents a type/subtype of the parametrized type `Pair<Integer>`. Therefore, I can either pass a `Pair<Integer>` or `SubPair<Integer>` to WildcardsMethod.

**Example 2 (makes sense):**

```
static void WildcardsMethod(List<? extends Pair<? super Number>> list)
{
    System.out.println("It worked");
}

static void TestWildcardsMethod()
{
    List<Pair<Number>> list = null;
    WildcardsMethod(list);
}
```

I look and see that I first need a `Pair<? super Number>` so I decide to pass in `Pair<Number>` resulting in the following code:

```
? extends Pair<Number>
```

I then look at the leftmost wildcard and see that I can use either `Pair<Number>` or `SubPair<Number>`. I end up passing `List<Pair<Number>>`.

So in other words, I see the deepest wildcard as asking for a subtype or supertype of the innermost bound (Number). I then go to the top level wildcard and look for a subtype/supertype of the generic type (Pair).

**Example 3 (doesn't make sense):**

```
static void WildcardsMethod(List<? super Pair<? super Number>> list)
{
    System.out.println("It worked");
}

static void TestWildcardsMethod()
{
    List<Pair<Object>> list = null;
    WildcardsMethod(list);
}
```

Well, in terms of `Pair<? super Number>`, Object is definitely a supertype of Number so `Pair<Object>` should work just as it did for the previous examples. The following is what I think of when trying to understand this:

```
? super Pair<Object>
```

So I am limited to either `Pair<Object>` or `SuperPair<Object>`. However, none of this works.

**Example 4 (doesn't make sense):**

```
static void WildcardsMethod(List<? super Pair<? extends Number>> list)
{
    System.out.println("It worked");
}

static void TestWildcardsMethod()
{
    List<Pair<Integer>> list = null;
    WildcardsMethod(list);
}
```

It's the same thing here. `Pair<Integer>` belongs to the family of `Pair<? extends Number>` resulting in the following:

```
? super Pair<Integer>
```

I can then pass in either `Pair<Integer>` or `SuperPair<Integer>` However, this too does not work.

So I am either thinking of this wrong and somehow that model works for extends but not for super or I am simply missing something about lowerbounds and nested wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1:**

1. Is `List<Pair<Integer>>` a subtype of `List<? extends Pair<? extends Number>>`?
2. It would be if `Pair<Integer>` is a subtype of `Pair<? extends Number>`. Is it?
3. Yes, because `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`.

**Example 2:**

1. Is `List<Pair<Number>>` a subtype of `List<? extends Pair<? super Number>>`?
2. It would be if `Pair<Number>` is a subtype of `Pair<? super Number>`. Is it?
3. Yes, because `Number` is a supertype of `Number`.

**Example 3:**

1. Is `List<Pair<Object>>` a subtype of `List<? super Pair<? super Number>>`?
2. It would be if `Pair<Object>` is a supertype of `Pair<? super Number>`. Is it?
3. No, it is not. A parameterized type with a specific parameter can never be a supertype of a parameterized type with a wildcard.

**Example 4:**

1. Is `List<Pair<Integer>>` a subtype of `List<? super Pair<? extends Number>>`?
2. It would be if `Pair<Integer>` is a supertype of `Pair<? extends Number>`. Is it?
3. No, it is not. A parameterized type with a specific parameter can never be a supertype of a parameterized type with a wildcard.

Comment: `Pair<Integer>` is not a `Pair<? super Number>`, but `Pair<Object>` is

Comment: Why is `Pair<Object>` considered subtype of `Pair<? super Number>`. Both are of the same type, so `List<? super Pair<>>` or `List<? extends Pair<>>` should both work right?

Comment: Alright, I think what was throwing me off was thinking about in pieces. When dealing with this level of nested cards, you have to actually think of the entire wildcard expression.

For example, `? extends Pair<? super Number>` means "Give me a member of the **set** for which `Pair<? super Number>` can contain. 

In a similar manner, `? super Pair<? super Number>` means "Give me a member of a **set** for which contains `Pair<? super Number>`.

In other words, you can't think of these as simply as the parts but rather the entire picture.

Comment: @Codebender: `Foo<A>` is a subtype of `Foo<? some bound>` if `A` satisfies the `? some bound`.